# Is there a maximal window's size in Pyglfw?

Tags: python, opengl, glfw, pyopengl

I used to to create context for frame buffer object images with width< 1061 using this code:

```
glfw.init()
glfw.window_hint(glfw.VISIBLE, False)
window = glfw.create_window(width, height, "My OpenGL window", None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)
```

And that work fine. For example, if I used: glGetDoublev(GL_VIEWPORT) I will get:

```
array([   0.,    0., 1300., 1000.])
```

But when I try to use the same code for an image with a width larger then 1061 I get:

```
array([   0.,    0., 1300., 1061.])
```

I am using PyOpenGl and PyGLFW on a windows machine.

Is 1061 a limitation of pyGLFW or do I Do something wrong?
If so, what is it?
Thanks,
Avi

Comment: To me, this sounds like you hit the height of the desktop for your particular resolution (1080px - some pixels for title bar and borders etc.).

Comment: Thanks, can it be overridden?

Comment: I don't know - but what is even the point? The contents of the  portion of the window which would be outside the desktop is completely undefined in the GL anyway, so there is no use to it. If you want off-screen rendering, use an FBO.

Comment: Thank you, but, I used this context to create off-screen rendering FBO. So it very important to my purpose to create larger frames.

Comment: O.k using: glViewport(0,0,width, height) between rendering to the FBO and saving the output solved the problem. thanks.